# FBX file structure changed after export from blender

Tags: unity, blender

I have a free character from asset store.
I uploaded it to mixamo and used it to create and download animation(pistol idle)
I decided to change it a bit in blender(only animation, I didn't change structure of the mesh or rig)  and export as FBX.
Here I faced a problem.
FBX file structure changed.How it was before opening in blender -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vt7Y.png

How it looks now -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqf2G.png

I tried different export settings but with no luck. I can't assign my avatar to this fbx object as structure is different.